# Accessing DB create by Django using psql

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

I am using `Django (version 1.8.2)` along with `PostgreSql (v 9.4.4)` on `python (v2.7.9 - anaconda distribution)` to create an application.

I am creating tables in database by defining them in `models.py` of `Django`. Once, I have created these tables I am able to view and add content of these tables in the browser `(http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/)`.

However, when I try to access these tables using `psql`, I get the error as `relation xyz_abc does not exist`, where `xyz_abc` is a table present in database as seen by using `\dt`.

I am not able to understand why this should be the case and any suggestions on how this tables can be accessed using `psql` will be really helpful.

**Edit**

Steps to access the database are -

1. Open the terminal in max
2. type 'pqsl' in terminal which opens the psql
3. `\c testdb` - this connects to the database which contains the table `xyz_abc`
4. once connected the, i try to select everything from the table using `select * from xyz_abc;`

Comment: How are you trying to access them exactly? Can you show me the query?

Comment: Using psql query, which is  `select * from xyz_abc;`. I m putting exact steps in question edit

Comment: Maybe the TableNames were in MixedCase?

Comment: @wildplasser if that would have been the case I would not post on stackoverflow

Comment: Can you access the database by Django ORM? Can you perform any other query operations except select on that table? Are you able to access other tables in that same database?

Comment: Yes I am able to access everything in DB from Django